# usb to wireless to usb

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, usb

I have a device that sends data (tx rx) over usb. I want to read out this data with a raspberry pi and use an existing library to read out the signal.
I need to read out this signal wirelessly. So ideally I'd like to have a USB - wireless - USB connection.

Since I don't want to rewrite the library I just want the signal to be send wirelessly but retrieved through usb. So basically I just want it to act like a usb cable over air or like a wireless mouse which plugs in with a receiver to your usb. Is there any off-the-shelf solution, or should I just give up and build my own (small microcontroller that sends the data over whatever wireless protocol I choose)

Comment: sounds a bit advanced for me, but that aside. i'll chime in. . What if you already have a network connection, (yeah wireless), between your devices, so then all you need is some software on each side that interfaces between the network and usb.

Comment: Problem is I can only put some software on one side of the interface (the raspberry pi). The other end is just a 'dumb tx / rx' side. I think my only solution is to create a small wireless chip that receives the tx rx data and sends it through a wireless protocol.

Comment: so if the other side had a windows calculator, then you couldn't even run that because you only have access to a usb connector of the other side?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need Virtual USB to accomplish wireless USB. 
Here's an image that sums up the idea:

[image: (IMAGE)]

(courtesy of https://www.virtualhere.com/home).

In the case of using the Raspberry Pi, then the "USB/IP project" would also be suitable.